# Solder bridging on vias

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, via

What's the possible risk of using a board with a solder splash on vias? I couldn't clean it and it's passed ICT test. please advise.
[image]

Comment: Use some solder wick to remove it.

Comment: Thank you guys for replaying back. I found that these via points are on the same plane, so regardless of the cosmetics side of it, it should be safe to use.

Answer (score 4):

The bridge looks very weakly attached, and would perhaps be prone to flaking off and shorting out another connection somewhere. Trivial job to clear it up, so no point in taking the risk!

Answer (score 3):

A short is a bad thing, and if it were a short the board shouldn't pass QC.

However, this is *not* a short, its a blob of solder which is connecting two vias which are part of the same net. It will not cause you any problems.

In this case, the blob was most likely formed by a soldering iron when the pins beside it were soldered.

---

In response to the good point by @DKNguyen, if this were a blob of solder stuck to the board with, say, flux residues or surface tension, it could fall off and cause problems later.

However, given that the OP couldn't remove it, its probably not so much a splash but a well bonded solder joint, in which case it's no more likely to fall off than any other solder joint.

A careful prod with a flat edge (e.g. screwdriver) would test whether or not it's likely to come off.

Comment: Is there a chance of it breaking off being so large a blob with such a small point actually adhering to the board? It's only actually adhering on the bottom edge more like a cantliever.

Comment: @DKNguyen good point. By the looks of it though, and given the OP couldn't remove it, the solder has taken properly to the board in which case its not likely to ever come off.

Comment: It didn't come of completely, but it does look better. and I found all these via point are on the same plane, so it is ok to use. Thank you.